# Add attribute to javascript function

Tags: javascript, json, function

I have javascript function who need add position attribute on object.

```
function conv(data){
var result=[];
function dfs(node, parent) {
    for(var i in node){
        result.push({id:node[i].id,pid:parent});
        if (node[i]['children']) dfs(node[i]['children'],node[i]['id']);
    }
}
dfs(data, 0);
return result;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrmoonlv/jG4FS/)

So I got result  = `[{"id":1,"pid":0},{"id":4,"pid":1},{"id":2,"pid":0}]`

Need add position something like:

```
[
{"id":1,"pid":0,"position":100}, // First root
{"id":4,"pid":1,"position":100}, // First sub root
{"id":5,"pid":1,"position":101}, // Second sub root
{"id":2,"pid":0,"position":101}, // Second root
{"id":3,"pid":0,"position":102}, // Third root
]
```

**UPDATE**

Position always starts from 100 so its var can be static.

Comment: Where does the value of `position` comes from, is it computed from the position on the tree ?

Comment: Oh Sory..See my update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further information, it seems you just need to add the `position` to the object you `push` in the array:

```
result.push({id:node[i].id,pid:parent,position:position});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jG4FS/1/)